# Are two (non nested) "for loops" iterating over the same size array of n = O(2n)

Tags: big-o

for example if we have

```
public void search(){
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
      .............
     }

 for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        .............
    }
 }
```

would search() be O(n) + O(n) = O(2n) ?

Comment: now what if my first for loop was O(n-i) and my second one was O(k), for some real numbers i, and k. would my Order be O(k + (n-i)) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the time is linear in n, but because constant factors are not interesting in O-notation, you can still write `O(n)`. Even if you had 10 consecutive for-loops from 1 to n, it would still be `O(n)`. Constant factors are dropped.

**Edit (answer to your comment):**

If i, n and k are independent, yes, it would be `O(k + (n-i))`.
But you could simplify it if you for example know that k = `O(n)`. (e.g. k ≈ n/2). Then you could write it as `O(n - i)` (because in `O(2n - i)`, the `2` is dropped).

If i and k are both linearly dependent on n, it would even be `O(n).`

Comment: now what if my first for loop was O(n-i) and my second one was O(k), for some real numbers i, and k.

would my Order be O(k + (n-i)) ?

Comment: What happens if the number of iterations in both loops are different? For example, first loop is iterated `m` times and second one is iterated `n` times where `n>>m`. Also, `n` is not the function of `m` , i.e `m` and `n` are independent. Will be complexity be `O(n)` or `O(m+n)` or `O(m)*O(n)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is O(2n) which is equivalent to saying it is O(n), the coefficient doesn't matter really.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation expresses time or space *complexity*. It does not measure time or space directly, it measures how the change in number of elements impacts time or space. While two loops are certainly slower than one, they both scale exactly the same: in direct proportion to `n`. That is what `O(n)` means.

(Slight simplification here, it does not account for why `O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)`, for example, but it should suffice for the matter at hand.)